# Blade templating conditional encoding apostrophes

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, lumen

Using Lumen 5.4.5.

I'm attempting to use a Blade templating conditional to only display a value if it is populated. Here is my syntax:

```
{{ ($board->a1 != '') ? "a1: '$board->a1'" : '' }}
```

Should render like this in browser:

```
a1: 'wR'
```

Instead it's rendering the HTML encoding string like this:

```
a1: &#039;wR&#039;
```

How can I successfully render the uncoded apostrophes in my Blade conditional?

Comment: Have you tried **`{!! ($board->a1 != '') ? "a1: '$board->a1'" : '' !!}`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the the call to `htmlspecialchars` automatically done with {{ }} using {!! !!} instead. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade